# How to force generic type param to conform to a certain signature

Tags: typescript

I want to put a `<T extends JsonRequest>` on a function signature to force any interfaces to  be serializable.

The error I get when trying this is:

```
Type 'AlertHistoryResponse' does not satisfy the constraint 'JsonRequest'.
  Type 'AlertHistoryResponse' is not assignable to type 'JsonObject'.
    Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'AlertHistoryResponse'.(2344)
```

I don't want to add an index signature to `AlertHistoryResponse` though; is there any way I can assert `AlertHistoryResponse` is a `JsonRequest`?

---

Code:

```
type JsonPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null;
type JsonObject = {
    [key: string]: JsonRequest | undefined  // allow undefined here because these keys will be stripped when stringified
}
type JsonMap = Map<string, JsonRequest>  // will be converted into an object
type JsonArray = Array<JsonRequest>;
type JsonSet = Set<JsonPrimitive>  // will be converted into an array

/**
 * Represents an object that can be serialized with jsonStringify() (not the native JSON.stringify)
 */
export type JsonRequest = JsonPrimitive | JsonObject | JsonArray | JsonSet | JsonMap

function createGetQuery<T extends JsonRequest>(route: string) {
    return null
}

interface AlertHistoryEntry {
    id: string,
    segmentNumber: number
    alert: string
    dateUtc: string
    user: string
}

interface AlertHistoryResponse {
    log: AlertHistoryEntry[]
    timezone?: string
}

export const useAlertHistoryQuery = createGetQuery<AlertHistoryResponse>('bookings.getAlertHistory')
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYAUBOBLAth4GBu0AvFHMJkgOZQA+USArlgEYRq1TMIIA2EAhkg6MePANwAoUJFiIkAeWYArCAGNgUEgG8JUPVADaAawggAXKXIYqAXQvxkAJQgBHBhDIcGSACYQAZtYQPnoA9KFQ-KIIAO5Q3n6BSMFQABZs0Kyq-Axw0MDpeVAmIHBQMRiinNBkmGCQITHpQrXWlBiBwRIAvlLg0A5IALL8YJpQI2AAPK1UADSyTq7uZAB8YREVVaxQqsiEaMAp1sAIkUIIymrAfTKDAIJoaPwg44-PIFODzm4ewKuSaQDOQAZQgGhIYOAXzk6GwuAIEHWUHC5UqPGqu32bCOIROZ0EkSeLwkElCACpybpyVBnGA0B4IEhgGVCZcVOooAV+BpskIdnlMFEMAAvFIVApQJSgqxUDogAAUAEooAqkAgNAVoEgeYjYCD5AA5AB0s3a-hASupoQkEAAHmAEIcuf1FkgfisIW64Tg8IQOINFByNHQHsTXqHQeCA3JJqT-N51BhkLsGTyIABxcEARXcaE+ABUoPajr4yt9ln9Vgq0AgGEcLGaVTp9FAGcAGGghCIeD1SSc2P5+KpoPc+IcABIYMhOkAAUWZ+agLf0GB8jdllDmun0eUoWCZwENTFYaAsjBYbB3eiiOI3FEo16gPnTAFVgKp720n7k2F+qH2EgDmgQ4jlAY44lOM75s4cCOkgRQrnoPAIJQFgQZO06nPmC7kCABg2E+eAHiKyAQAA-P+j69LaDpOryyCeL+GHAFB2EgLmbCvCQqhpkcWbAJx+ZTCxbGzrB8F5NWADkXAIEYbRwMalDgqJWGztJSpAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `interface` won't satisfy the index signature requirement because it can have new fields added to it (open). Use a `type` alias instead (closed). See [Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) in the TS handbook.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYGUICcCWBDANpgL2wCNdoBeKYhBM7JKAHyiQFcBbYjJl13XHnGBYkAcx7xkaLHkIkyAbQC6PAN5QFAawggAXFCEjRS-ZNQYc+IqQgBuKAF9bAWABQb0JFiIkAWWxgUJT+YAA8hphiADTeUhay1mQAfFBQAPRpUADumPxU0ADGyABuGMAQACZQkcAIUPRQCMQAVhAFwB7g0GZowEFQvaE98VbyECnpmTl5XFBFSKXo5VU1dQ3Y6OjYIG6dXtKWcjb9wzKjx8xmIRI+vS7urgBmrEjtmMhz6BDY5QDiEMAAIqsDAgKChAAqUAgAA9ykgKnABiMjskABToBCscr6CJiACUUFUblSX2ArHQDDY-HuDl2rk80AAgmQlgAJTBCBDoEAAUSQwjBlGJrlSmAquOEkVE91ScAgonYEAFADkOFx0Po2JwMLL6qzgJKjHqKj8IABVYAFI3SvWseWagxSsS0+57ZkGjlcnkAJQgcDAyHl-RFqVwCFE+hZZS9tR5-MFyj1wEwSoIyAgAH4bS63E56fMhFB7RBo+zOXGQMDQf0Cl8zf8gSCeaEy8BY9yQH6A0HxmiAOTUBCaaVwAB0ogBbY7PP7+PuQA)

```ts
type JsonSerializable = boolean | number | null | string | JsonSerializable[] | { [key: string]: JsonSerializable; };

type JsonMap = Map<string, JsonSerializable>  // will be converted into an object
type JsonSet = Set<JsonSerializable>  // will be converted into an array

type Serializable = JsonSerializable | JsonMap | JsonSet;

function createGetQuery <T extends Serializable>(route: string) {
  return null;
}

type AlertHistoryEntry = {
  id: string;
  segmentNumber: number;
  alert: string;
  dateUtc: string;
  user: string;
};

type AlertHistoryResponse = {
  log: AlertHistoryEntry[];
  timezone?: string;
};

const useAlertHistoryQuery = createGetQuery<AlertHistoryResponse>('bookings.getAlertHistory');
```

Comment: Huh! I thought they were nearly identical. That's good to know, thank you